# LINQ to SQL: How to implement a LEAST or similar function?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, function

**Given:**

A table named TABLE_1 with the following columns:

- ID
- ColumnA
- ColumnB
- ColumnC
- ColumnD

I have SQL query where TABLE_1 joins on itself twice based off of ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC. The query might look something like this:

```
Select t1.ID, t2.ID, t3.ID, LEAST(t1.ColumnD, t2.ColumnD, t3.ColumnD)
  From TABLE_1 t1
  Left Join TABLE_1 t2 On
       t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA
   And t1.ColumnB = t2.ColumnB
   And t1.ColumnC = t2.ColumnC
  Left Join TABLE_1 t3 On
       t2.ColumnA = t3.ColumnA
   And t2.ColumnB = t3.ColumnB
   And t2.ColumnC = t3.ColumnC
```

**Problem:**

I need that Query to be rewritten in LINQ. I've tried taking a stab at it:

```
var query =
    from t1 in myTABLE1List // List<TABLE_1>
    join t2 in myTABLE1List
      on new {t1.ColumnA, t1.ColumnB, t2.ColumnC}
  equals new {t2.ColumnA, t2.ColumnB, t2.ColumnC}
    join t3 in myTABLE1List
      on new {t2.ColumnA, t2.ColumnB, t2.ColumnC}
  equals new {t3.ColumnA, t3.ColumnB, t3.ColumnC}
  select new {
    ID_1 = s1.ID,
    ID_2 = s2.ID,
    ID_3 = s3.ID,
    // Invalid anonymous type member declarator.
    // Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment,
    // simple name or member access.
    // how can I implement this?
    least(s1.ColumnD, s2.ColumnD, s3.ColumnD)
  };

....

private object least(params object[] objects)
{
  // code here that sorts the objects and returns the 'smallest' of them.

  return leastObject;
}
```

How do I write my query in LINQ? What am I doing wrong? I thought it was possible to use functions inside of LINQ expressions, so why am I getting this error?

Comment: whats LEAST(...)? is that some custom UDF in your environment?

Comment: I should also note that these are string values (they are numbers in a varchar column. Why isn't this column an int you say? Great question... the boss doesn't want it to be an int in case we get non-numeric data from our clients... which COULD happen.)

Comment: @K Ivanov, LEAST is from Oracle its like Math.Min or calling MIN(Column) except that its find the least value of multiple columns in a record, not multiple records in a column.

Comment: What should be the return value of least, if all/one of the arguments are non-numeric and/or null?

Comment: @shahkalpesh see this: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/least.php I haven't written this function yet but its compiling. I'll figure that one out on my own, I just need to make sure that I can call it from LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I *think* you need to assign the result of `least` to an actual member of your new anonymous type instance, e.g.:

```
select new {
    ID_1 = s1.ID,
    ID_2 = s2.ID,
    ID_3 = s3.ID,
    Least = least(s1.ColumnD, s2.ColumnD, s3.ColumnD)
};
```

Comment: I think that might do it buddy! :D

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
MinOfColumnD = Math.Min(Math.Min(s1.ColumnD, s2.ColumnD), s3.ColumnD))
```

EDIT: Assuming that ColumnD in each of the table is numeric & 'least` (in this context) is minimum of 3 numbers in the given columns.

EDIT: If the columns are string, determine what max. values it can hold & do a `.Parse` on it.
For e.g.

```
MinOfColumnD = Math.Min(Math.Min(int.Parse(s1.ColumnD), int.Parse(s2.ColumnD)), int.Parse(s3.ColumnD)))
```

Comment: good call except that these are string columns. (Don't ask me why they aren't ints... they should be but my boss doesn't want them to be incase we get data that ISN'T a number)

Comment: @DJ if the data in those 'string' columns is expected to be number the query will fail run time in those cases, not a good practice, +1 for the answer though